# Find natural number $0 < n < 30,000$ such that $\sqrt[3]{5n}+\sqrt{10n}$ is rational

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I was thinking that I could try to make some sort of substitution to convert $\sqrt[3]{5n}+\sqrt{10n}$ into a polynomial with integer coefficients then use the Rational Roots Theorem to find a rational root. I don't really know if that's going to get me anywhere other than $n=0$.

I would really appreciate some help, or some hints. I don't necessarily want a full solution, but a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should focus on the prime factorization of $n$.  To have a number be a cube, all the primes in its factorization need to come with a power that is a multiple of $3$.  Similarly, to be a square the primes need to have an even power.

In your example, all primes except $2$ and $5$ must be sixth powers.  Think about what the leading coefficients do for $2$ and $5$.

Comment: by leading coefficients you mean in the prime factorization?

Comment: By leading coefficients I mean the $5$ and $10$ under the radical signs.  They mean you don't want the powers of $2$ and $5$ in $n$ to be multiples of $6$.

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes much more sense. I think I figured it out. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I think the limit of $30,000$ is unfortunately low.  I think it should have been chosen large enough for there to be half a dozen solutions or so.

Comment: Its a question from a previous final exam for a topics in abstract mathematics course. The goal of the course is to have students become more proficient at reading and writing proofs, while also picking up useful nuggets for upper year courses. Answering these questions requires that we be sharp with concepts and theorems.

Comment: I just would like to have people recognize that once they find the smallest solution, which is $2^35^5=25,000$ they can multiply it by the sixth power of any number, including $2$ and $5$ and get another solution.